# Angular 4 change layout

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have this two layouts:

```html
<div *ngIf="!loginPanel" class="login1">
<a (click)="showLoginPanel()">Login</a>
</div>

<div *ngIf="loginPanel" class="login2">
<input type="text" placeholder="user">
<input type="password" placeholder="placeholder">
</div>
```

and the typescript:

```js
public loginPanel: boolean;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginPanel = false;
  }

  showLoginPanel() {
    this.loginPanel = true;
  }
```

In fact, the first div disappear when i click on login. but the second div doesn't replace the first. does anyone know how to do this correctly?

Comment: When you click on login it removes the button from dom and adds form view.

Comment: but it's not happening, only the first div is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the ngif else

```
<div *ngIf="!loginPanel; else loginForm" class="login1">
    <a (click)="showLoginPanel()">Login</a>
</div>

<ng-template #loginForm>
    <div class="login2">
      <input type="text" placeholder="user">
      <input type="password" placeholder="placeholder">
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: in your code both divs appear. should be the first or the second

Answer (score 0):

i solve the problem. the else div should be ng-template... so, now its working.
thanks anyway